# Getting Minor Version Mismatch Error with Php and Mysql

Tags: centos, yum, mysql, php5

I randomly started getting this error when trying to instantiate a `new mysqli` instance in php script:

> mysqli::mysqli(): Headers and client library minor version mismatch.
>   Headers:50541 Library:50626

I'm a little bit confused because when I run `sudo yum list installed`, the versions look to be the same.  Either way, running `sudo yum update` does nothing to actually update the packages.

Here is the output for `sudo yum list installed`(just php packages):

```
php.x86_64                  5.4.16-36.el7_1                          @updates
php-cli.x86_64              5.4.16-36.el7_1                          @updates
php-common.x86_64           5.4.16-36.el7_1                          @updates
php-devel.x86_64            5.4.16-36.el7_1                          @updates
php-mbstring.x86_64         5.4.16-36.el7_1                          @updates
php-mcrypt.x86_64           5.4.16-3.el7                             @epel
php-mssql.x86_64            5.4.16-3.el7                             @epel
php-mysql.x86_64            5.4.16-36.el7_1                          @updates
php-pdo.x86_64              5.4.16-36.el7_1                          @updates
php-soap.x86_64             5.4.16-36.el7_1                          @updates
```

I am using `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)`, `PHP 5.4.16` and `5.6.26 MySQL Community Server`.

I saw on other answers to this question that you can install the `php-mysqlnd` driver, but that driver isn't listed under yum's packages.

Here are the php packages I can install through yum:

```
php.x86_64                                 5.4.16-36.el7_1             @updates 
php-cli.x86_64                             5.4.16-36.el7_1             @updates 
php-common.x86_64                          5.4.16-36.el7_1             @updates 
php-devel.x86_64                           5.4.16-36.el7_1             @updates 
php-mbstring.x86_64                        5.4.16-36.el7_1             @updates 
php-mcrypt.x86_64                          5.4.16-3.el7                @epel    
php-mssql.x86_64                           5.4.16-3.el7                @epel    
php-mysql.x86_64                           5.4.16-36.el7_1             @updates 
php-pdo.x86_64                             5.4.16-36.el7_1             @updates 
php-soap.x86_64                            5.4.16-36.el7_1             @updates
```

Anybody know how I can resolve this issue?  I don't know why this would randomly crop up like this.  The scripts were working before I left for the weekend on Friday and, so far as I know, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve using `sudo yum install php-mysqlnd`.  I must have mistyped it when trying to install the first time.  Doh!

After installing `php-mysqlnd` run `sudo service httpd restart`.

Apparently a coworker messed with our `mysql` drivers. Asked if he changed anything that had to do with `php` or `mysql` and he told me he didn't.  Looked at `.bash_history` and saw that he reinstalled `php` and a bunch of `mysql` drivers.

Lesson learned!

Comment: Had to do `yum remove php-mysql` before this solution because the two packages conflicted.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this mistake by going to php Extensions and disable mysqli then enable nd_mysqli .
Good luck

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are
better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).